# Sites selection popups after failed submitting question with invalid tag on Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, asking-questions

When the "*Ask question*" form reappears after trying to submit a question with an invalid tag, the "*Ask on which site?*" text/search box has focus, this then brings up all sites.

Shouldn't the search only trigger popup after a few characters have been entered?

To reproduce :

1. Try to submit question with non-existing tag.
2. Notice "*Tag not valid*" message.
3. Press edit.
4. Question form reappears with popup of all sites.

Offending question and the result after pressing *Edit*

[image: question in question]
[image: all sites shown in popup]

<sup>(Image resized, click to see the full size)</sup>

Comment: Cannot repro on v1.0.83. The tag selection is now using smart-search, thus you can't enter non-existing tag. ([The app doesn't allow creation of new tag either](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213606/allow-creating-new-tags))