# Allow creating new tags with mobile app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, ios-app, tag-creation

How do I create a new tag in the mobile iOS/ Android app? This operation is currently not supported.

When I tap the tags section, a search window opens; when I type something not existing and press Done, the tag section remains blank.

Please add such option to the apps. It is specially important in case of newly launched sites.

Comment: I hope you don't mind me generalising this to the iOS app as well! (Although I'm not sure if the mobile devs would 
prefer these being posted separately...?

Comment: Man, we get enough typo tags as it is, I'm not sure how things'd look once mobile keyboards get involved...

Comment: @Charles easy enough to add warning when adding new tag i.e. confirm dialog "Are you sure you want to create the new tag [name here]"?

Comment: There is a bug that allows the user to [create a new tag on SE Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278640).

Answer (score 4):

I am in full support of this.

[As I've stated on a similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/292712/351462), the current restriction for creating tags on mobile feels a bit arbitrary. You can workaround the restriction for creating tags on mobile by opening Chrome or Safari and requesting the desktop version of the site.

This restriction is especially noticeable on media-based sites like Arqade or Movies & TV. It’s frustrating to not be able ask questions about a new game or movie when [a tag hasn’t been created yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tT4NN.jpg).

Stack Exchange already shows a warning prompt when making a new tag on certain sites. To address the concern of potential misspelled tags, this warning could be enabled on all sites for the mobile.

If a user has the required rep to create a tag, I don't think their choice of platform should act as a limitation.

Comment: The warning prompt isn't enabled on all sites.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog In that case, tag creation on mobile should probably show the warning on all sites to prevent typos.