# Tag field can be input freely when editing a question on Android app

Tags: bug, tags, edits, android-app, asking-questions

When editing a question, the tag field can be focused, and freely input after pressing "next" on some keyboards when the text cursor is on "Edit summary"

Steps to reproduce:

1. Suggest edit a question (e.g. this)
2. Tap "Edit summary" field
3. Tap "Next" or "Arrow" symbol on the keyboard (e.g. Google Keyboard/Gboard)
4. The tag field *itself* now receives the focus, and any text can be input
5. Non-existent tag will also be created

[image: back to alpha version?]

- App Version: 1.0.85 (still repro on 1.0.95)
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: Nexus 5

  - OS Version: 6.0.1 (2704746)