# Creating tags from SE app

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-creation, mobile-app

I am currently using SE app for Android. I just posted a travel question but could not create a new tag for my question.

I know that:

1. This is SO meta, and my issue is with travel, but I am afraid that this applies to all SE sites
   2 I don't have yet enough reputation to create a tag autonomously on Travel like I can on SO, but at my level it should be possible to peer review tag creation requests

Is it possible to create question tags from android SE app? I have tagged this question with only existing tags but could not find a way to create a new one. On the site, if you tab/enter without picking an existing tag the page will propose to create, but eventually can fail when you submit the form if you have very low rep (this MIGHT have changed by the time I had low rep on SO)

OR it is just that I haven't yet learned to use the application

Comment: There's no way to create tags in the mobile app, regardless of the version.

Comment: @Catija is correct, and there never will be. The apps won't be developed any further.

Comment: If you want to try... [Tag field can be input freely when editing a question on Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278640)