# Can you create tags in the Stack Exchange iOS app?

Tags: support, bug, ios-app

I seem to be able to search for tags, but not to create. I double-checked that I do have the create tags privilege.

Comment: Eh, doesn't it work just like on the sites? When asking/editing a question adding a new tag to it? There's never been a "create tag" page on the sites either.

Comment: @Oded No. It's not possible to create tags in the app. :(

Comment: I'd expect that's by design then.

Comment: There's a FR for it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213606/allow-creating-new-tags).

Comment: @Catija so that's a dupe.

Comment: @ShadowWizard support is not a feature request... that is asking for it to be made possible, this is asking if it is possible.

Comment: @Catija the answer is trivial: "no". So in those cases, the next step is "OK. so can this be added?", and then it's dupe. Just saving that extra step. (Not worth posting answer of "No", IMO)