# Search tag is not good system

Tags: support, android-app

When I first opened the app I could write my own tag but after while only search tag was available. It was annoying as I couldn't add new tag.

Comment: I am not a 100% sure what you're asking about, but you cannot simply add new tags below a certain reputation.

Comment: What kind of reputation do I need to add my own tags.

Comment: It is shown in each sites [help center/privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) section.

Comment: At this site it's 500 minimum: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ SO is at 1500 other sites 300, beta sites 150.

Comment: @rene That's why I said it's 500 ***here***.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that is why I thought to help you out with the other rep-levels ...

Comment: @RiyadhKabir your question is not clear. You can't add new tag anywhere in Stack Exchange, unless you have other account with more rep which is not linked to this account of yours. The app never gives a user more privileges than they have in the website.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I think it is better if newbies could get the freedom to add their own tag. Because like my situation not all tags can be found in search tag

Comment: @RiyadhKabir And I thoroughly disagree with that FR. Those privileges are installed for good reasons.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ worth to mention, that even with enough reputation, [we can't add new tags via the app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213606/allow-creating-new-tags-with-mobile-app). android is the same since it's API limitation as far as I can tell.

Comment: The tags are used to enable users to find questions. Having users that are new to the network create tags on the fly would add many tags (let alone the misspelled ones) that would probably only see one or two questions. We think that is far from useful and that is why the restriction exists. I can't imagine there aren't broader tags that can be applied in those case where a new tag would be beneficial. Each per site meta is open for tag requests where these request are judged by the other members of the community before it is created.

Comment: I mean not to add teg in network but only in the post.

Comment: @RiyadhKabir "I mean not to add teg in network but only in the post." If you could do that, the tag would be added to the network. If you don't find an appropriate tag, add details to your question. As well you should clearly show that the question matches the selected tags.

Comment: @RiyadhKabir What benefit would it add to have question only related tags?

Comment: What is the role of tag anyway.

Comment: @RiyadhKabir As it's mentioned as description if you goto the [all tags overview](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags): _"A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other, similar questions. Using the right tags makes it easier for others to find and answer your question."_ So you see it only makes sens if there are already other questions categorized like yours. But  that doesn't mean everyone should be trusted to do such categorization properly.

Answer (score 1):

> When I first opened the app I could write my own tag ...

Probably you noticed that because your tag matched one of the already existing ones in the site you've chosen.

> ... but after while only search tag was available.

That was probably because the tag you where trying to enter didn't match any existing.

---

> It was annoying<sup>1</sup> as I couldn't add new tag.

Besides you cannot do that from the [android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app), you can add tags only with a certain reputation. The exact numbers are site specific, but can be found in every site's help center at the Privileges section.

Have a look at the explanation from the [all tags overview](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags) page (emphasis mine):

> > A tag is a keyword or label that ***categorizes your question with other, similar questions***. Using the right tags makes it easier for others to find and answer your question.

That you can't add tags without this minimum reputation is made up for reasons:

- You should have gained some knowledge about the existing tags at the site, and how to use them properly for creating or editing questions
- If tags could be created arbitrarily by everyone, they wouldn't add any benefit for focused searching.

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>That something just *annoys* you isn't usually a good reasoning for a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request). At least you should add a comprehensive proposal what exactly should be changed, and how so in detail.</sub>