# What's with the tagging limitations in the mobile app?

Tags: bug, tags, ios-app, tag-synonyms

Normally, when you ask a question you can begin typing a tag, and you will receive autocomplete suggestions based on existing tags. For example, the tag [question-quality](/questions/tagged/question-quality):

[image: Screenshot of tag suggesting mechanism]

The system does not only give you suggestions based on primary tags, it also gives you suggestions based on tag synonyms. For example, [bad-questions](/questions/tagged/bad-questions) is a synonym of the above tag:

[image: Screenshot of tag suggesting mechanism]

However, on the mobile app (iOS V. 1.6.6.2), tag synonyms do not exist:

[image: Screenshot of question-quality tag in the app showing no synonyms]

[image: Screenshot of tag search for bad-questions in the app showing no results]

So if someone is trying to ask a question using the app, they will be unable to find the [question-quality](/questions/tagged/question-quality) tag via the synonym. They also will be unable to manually use the [bad-questions](/questions/tagged/bad-questions) tag, because apparently you also can't *create* a tag using the app:

[image: Screenshot of trying to add a tag using the app]

As you can see, if no existing tag comes up, there is no option to add it.

There is already a largely ignored [feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213606/allow-creating-new-tags-with-mobile-app) asking for the ability to create tags via the app.

But why are there no tag synonyms in the app? Is this a bug that can be fixed (with the obvious caveat that the app is not currently being worked on), or is this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)?

Comment: [Great question +1](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48344279#48344279)